# Angular and jquery dynamic binding of plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a sample APP, where I need to rotate say a list of todo Items in Angular. so instead of display the todos in a list, I want just one item at a time and rotate the rest one by one. I am using jquery cycle plugin to acheive the effect, since the todos are getting added at run time, the jquery cycle plugin isn't picking the changes. Any suggestions how to acheive this.

I have put up a sample Demo

```
    var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.guys = ['Mike','Zerrra','Rick','Tom','Silva','Pollo'];
  $scope.addPerson = function() {
    $scope.guys.push($scope.newPerson);
    $scope.newPerson = '';
  }
});


app.directive('rp', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $(elem).cycle({
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                speed: 'slow',
                timeout: 1000,
                prev: '.prev',
                next: '.next'
            }); 
    }
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WK2Fg/119/

Comment: i think your plugin only works with images

Comment: no thats not the case, I have used it with text also.

Comment: Look at the console, cycle is undefined. $(elem) uses angular's jquery lite in your fiddle, instead of full version of jquery. So your plugging and jquery library should be linked earlier I guess.

Comment: Also remove html, body, head and script tags from your fiddle

Comment: @PashaZavoiskikh I have to use ng-app in html tag, thats why I have html tag there. Also the order you described doesn't matter as long as jquery is first

Comment: here is a working version of the fiddle (without console errors at least) http://jsfiddle.net/WK2Fg/123/ you don't have to have ng-app in html tag

Comment: @Mike ok, now we can start to work on the actual problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is jsfiddle of my solution. Is that what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/WK2Fg/126/

```
var app = angular.module('Application', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    debugger;
  $scope.guys = ['Mike','Zerrra','Rick','Tom','Silva','Pollo'];
  $scope.addPerson = function() {
      debugger;
    $scope.guys.push($scope.newPerson);
    $scope.newPerson = '';
  }
});


app.directive('rp', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { guys: "=" },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
      scope.$watch('guys', function(value) {
          debugger;
          $(elem).empty();

          $.each(value, function(){
              var guy = this;
              $(elem).append("<li>"+ guy +"</li>");
          });

          $(elem).cycle({
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                speed: 'slow',
                timeout: 1000,
                prev: '.prev',
                next: '.next'
            });
      }, true);
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container" ng-app="Application">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <a href="#" class="left">Left</a>
        <ul class="middle" guys="guys"  rp ></ul>
      <a href="#" class="right">Right</a>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newPerson" />
      <button ng-click="addPerson()">Add Person</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

P.S.

I am not very familiar with the jQuery plugin you are using to do the cycling, so currently I reset it after adding new elements. If this plugin has some functions that add new elements on the go, you can change the watch, to achieve smoother experience. I hope basing on my answer you'll figure out the rest.

Comment: hey thanks, it is certainly working but why is it adding two li items to DOM. I am sure this is not a plugin problem but something with the angular scope, I guess

Comment: @Mike How do you reproduce the problem? I don't see it in my fiddle, after I click once only one li element is added... screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/eriaq1ydn/

Comment: hmmm sorry dude I too can't reproduce this as a stand alone issue. but I just faced another problem with your code, DO you know what is the reason the function is not getting called when you inject the element that you call function from. http://jsfiddle.net/WK2Fg/129/

Comment: @Mike Angular just doesn't work like this. You are trying to achieve something that is not in the original question. Tell me what your final goal is and I will try to implement it when I have free time.

Comment: @Mike Or if you have big plans on using angular, I recommend you watch educational videos on https://egghead.io/ .

Comment: Thanks Dude, basically I am trying to built a dummy commenting system as a learning experience like discuss or livefyre. I am putting up small blocks together, while I have done good progress but there is something where I get stuck and I hook up to stackoverflow. Basically I have a problem where I am unable to call a function when called from a directive defined element. I reprodiced the same problem as in the fiddle. If you can help that would be awesome. But please, I dont want you to waste time on building somethng that I need. I am doing this as a learning thing and I appreciate your help